# the process can not access the file 'bin\debug' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

this is my code
i have tried every step i can find
i have moved con.close(); before and after it is still not working
please guide me to what to do
thank you
I am following this youtube video to make the crud operation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7ukAjQtsxE

````
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace crudingtime
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-6381H14\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yarabthis;Integrated Security=True");
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetEmpList();
        }

        private void imtired_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            int id = int.Parse(idbox.Text);
            string fname=fnametxt.Text, lname=lnametxt.Text;
            SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("exec ughh'"+id+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','",con);
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully inserted");
        }
        void GetEmpList()
        {
            SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("exec Listughh", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sd=new SqlDataAdapter(c);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sd.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: You get the error at compile time in Visual Studio?

Comment: yes when i am running the program

Comment: if you you right click your project and select clean, will the bin\debug folder be empty?

Comment: make sure you dispose your connection object and your data adapter.

Comment: Did you get an error connecting to the database? Did this cause the project to fail to start？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't try and persist the connection at the form class level - since then you can't control when you dispose of it.

So, try say like this, and always have a using code block (which will clean up all your connections for you).

And it not clear why you have a public form method here, so let's just leave that issue out of the picture for the time being.

and I assume that a hard coded connection string was JUST for this post, not that you are using hard coded connection strings all over the place - (don't do that!!!).

And you tagged this as asp.net so we assuem this is a web page, right?

Thus, this "air code" should suffice:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            GetEmpList();
    }

    private void imtired_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(idbox.Text);
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("ughh");
        c.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        c.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fnametxt.Text;
        c.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lnametxt.Text;
        MyRstP(c, false);

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully inserted");
    }
    void GetEmpList()
    {
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("Listughh");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataGridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(c);
        DataGridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL, bool returnData = true)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (returnData)
                {
                    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                }
                else
                {
                    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And as for that file in use.

Reboot your computer.

So, "isolate" your connection routine(s). Don't attempt to persist the connection at the form/class level, move your connection string to config or settings. (and bonus points is  you can use the connection builder).

Comment: it can easily be disposed at any level when wrapped in a try..catch..finally, but certainly a using is more appropriate